# Scikit learn for R

Tags: machine-learning, r

In Python, there's scikit learn package which unifies a large number of machine learning/data processing methods under uniform interface.

Is there anything similar to it for R?

Comment: R's formula interface is already used across many packages, & extended by some. The [`caret`](http://topepo.github.io/caret/index.html) package imposes greater uniformity. Have a look at the ["Machine Learning & Statistical Learning" Task View](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/MachineLearning.html) to see what's available on CRAN.

Answer (score 1):

## 1. caret

caret has been used by me with success: http://caret.r-forge.r-project.org/

## 2. MLR

There is also the MLR package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mlr/index.html

From the site:

> Interface to a large number of classification and regression
>   techniques, including machine-readable parameter descriptions. There
>   is also an experimental extension for survival analysis, clustering
>   and general, example-specific cost-sensitive learning. Generic
>   resampling, including cross-validation, bootstrapping and subsampling.
>   Hyperparameter tuning with modern optimization techniques, for single-
>   and multi-objective problems. Filter and wrapper methods for feature
>   selection. Extension of basic learners with additional operations
>   common in machine learning, also allowing for easy nested resampling.
>   Most operations can be parallelized.

I have tried and used MLR and it works nicely.

Answer (score 1):

I like ['h2o'](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/h2o/h2o.pdf).

It has:

- Aggregator
- Principal Component Analysis (pca)
- k-means
- Deep Learning
- Distributed Random Forest (rf)
- Gradient Boosted Machine (gbm)
- Generalized Linear model (glm)
- Generalized Low-Rank model (glrm)
- Naive Bayes

These are all wired into a single interface.  It is good at using all the cores on your machines, and having interfaces to a number of development environments.  You can access in a multitude of languages (java, R, web-based, spark, ...)

I like to run thing in r/h2o and watch live via the H2O flow interface.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the library *tidymodels* (https://www.tidymodels.org), a collection of packages for modelling and machine learning using *tidyverse* principles.
*Tidymodels* is the successor to the *caret* package.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

No.To my knowledge, there is no single package in R that unifies supervised and unsupervised machine learning methods (and documentation) in a similar way that scikit-learn does for Python. But as Scortchi commented, the R formula interface for expressing your model is used in many of the individual R packages.